# XSLT contains() and empty tag

Tags: xslt, contains

I have a problem with XSLT 1.0 contains() function and empty tags.

I have this xslt stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="test/tester">
            <test>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="contains('11,22,33', .)"/>
            </test>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the input is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
    <tester>11</tester>
    <tester>22</tester>
    <tester>33</tester>
    <tester>xx</tester>
    <tester/>
</test>
```

Result is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>11: true</test>
<test>22: true</test>
<test>33: true</test>
<test>xx: false</test>
<test>: true</test>
```

Problem here is that I expect the `contains()` function to return false if the `<tester>` tag is empty. However it is returning true for the last line. How can I avoid this, other than checking the tag value first for emptiness and setting a variable to some value I know is not on the list of values?

Thanks!

Comment: but `fn:contains` works correctly because your string actually contains an empty string. You should change the logic by f.i. processing with `contains` only tags which have contents or whatever.

Comment: @Alex I would understand if empty string contains an empty string, but not that '11,22,33' contains an empty string. But thats just me :)

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and for a complete, short and easy solution. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is the standard, as per [W3C Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-contains) behavior**.

**To avoid this, use**:

```
contains(',11,22,33,', concat(',', ., ','))
```

Answer (score 2):

XPath 1.0 spec is pretty vague on the matter, but XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0 Functions specification [explicitly declares](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-contains):

```
If the value of $arg2 is the zero-length string, then the function returns true.
```

I don't think it's a something new, just a clarification of an old functionality.

Comment: +1 Correct explanation. In logic terms, any set contains the empty set.